# Check In another user's file in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

The Microsoft support site (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/check-out-check-in-or-discard-changes-to-files-in-a-library-7e2c12a9-a874-4393-9511-1378a700f6de) says that with suitable permissions it is possible to Check In a file that has been Checked Out by another user and this should retain any changes they have made whereas discarding the Check In will lose them. Even with Site Admin privileges I have been unable to locate this option and wonder if it has been withdrawn?

I have looked within the Library Settings at "Manage files which have no checked in version" but this does not show files which are Checked Out within a Document Set in that Library. I don't know if this is because a Checked In version does exist - the previous version - but suspect that may be the reason.

Can anyone advise if this option is still available or not?

Answer (score 0):

The option only works for files with no checked in version.

Per my test, if I try to check in a page which is checked out by other user currently, I will get the message that "Do you want to override this check out now?"
[image]

When I click ok, it will not lose any changes made to the file. So you could use this wat to check in another user's file.